# I am trying to code a reset button for my Unity game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reset

I used the code that comes with all games and attempted to modify it a bit so that way you could press a key with your fingers instead of using the mouse. This was because in my first person game the mouse would lock and when I unlocked it to press the reset GUI it would simply lock back on. So I did a little research and here is my code that does not currently work. Please help and thank you in advance.

```
    using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelReset :MonoBehaviour , IPointerClickHandler
{

 void Update()
where (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J))
{
    // reload the scene
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetSceneAt(0).name);
}


private void Update()
{
}
}
```

Comment: Please note I am a beginner

Comment: I can't get your question correctly. Are you trying to implement touch on screen instead of mouse or keyboard buttons events.

Comment: There is no such thing as `where(...)` in C#. You probably want `if`. Also you cannot just put your code in a class. It has to be in a method, except properties, fields, events... obviously. Also you have `void Update` twice. You cannot declare the same method with the same parameters twice.

Comment: @FCin what you are saying is change the "where" to "if"  and remove the second void update but what do you mean about putting my code in a class?

Comment: Go through a basic tutorial for C#. Add missing `{}` around `Update()` method.

Comment: The have a function (`void Update`) declared twice. Also you used `where` instead of `if`. Please learn C# before moving forward. You will save your self time if you do so.

Answer (score 1):

change to this:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelReset :MonoBehaviour , IPointerClickHandler
{

   void Update(){
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("j"))
    {
      // reload the scene
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
   }

}
```